# "An IndexedDB transaction that was not yet complete has been aborted due to page navigation"

Tags: javascript, firefox, indexeddb

I'm using IndexedDB to store some data. It appears to work, but if I refresh the page, I see: `An IndexedDB transaction that was not yet complete has been aborted due to page navigation.` in the browser console on Firefox (36.0.4). I'm using this (local) file to test:

```
<html>
  <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
  <body>
    <script>
var request = window.indexedDB.open("test_db", 2);
request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
  request.result.createObjectStore("test_store");
};

request.onsuccess = function (event) {
  var db = request.result;
  var transaction = db.transaction(["test_store"], "readwrite");
  var put = transaction.objectStore("test_store").put("key", "value");
  transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
    console.log("Transaction complete");
  };
};
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I perform multiple transactions, I get multiple errors. If I have an `onclick` handler that performs a transaction and I click it several times, refreshing prints one error for each transaction I made in the past.

All this makes me think my transactions aren't being cleaned up. What do I need to do to finish a transaction?

My `oncomplete` handler is being called. Refreshing a few times, the browser console looks like this:

```
"Transaction complete" test.html:16:1
An IndexedDB transaction that was not yet complete has been aborted due to page navigation. test.html:13:0
"Transaction complete" test.html:16:1
An IndexedDB transaction that was not yet complete has been aborted due to page navigation. test.html:13:0
"Transaction complete" test.html:16:1
```

Test page (Ctrl-Shift-J to open console, then Ctrl-R to refresh shows the error):

http://test.roscidus.com/static/idb.html

Comment: If your "oncomplete" is firing then IndexedDb seems to believe transaction is complete. Does this happen straight after you clear down the browser cache?

Comment: Could you make a web page to reproduce your problem? It could be browser bug.

Comment: @KyawTun I've added a link to a test page at the end of the question. I tested using a new Firefox profile.

Comment: Reported as a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1147942

Comment: Have you tried to close the db connection after you finished with it?

Comment: Looks like they have a patch now.

Comment: Fixed in [tag:firefox] `41`, stable release will be shipped in September 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The error [was a bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1147942), and now it's already fixed:

> Status: RESOLVED FIXED

The fix was done on Firefox 41, [which was released on Sep 22th 2015](http://release.mozilla.org/planning/2015/01/13/release-schedule.html).

> Tracking Flags: status-firefox41: fixed